# Fields Are missings While importing dll file

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I had created a C# library project and add a model in the project.

```
public class sampleClass
   {
       public const string CREATE = "Create";
       public const string UPDATE = "Update";
       public const string UPDATEINSERT = "UpdateInsert";
       public const string DELETE = "Delete";
       public const string QUERY= "Query";     
   }
```

After building the project I need to use it another project. I create the build of the first project
and add the generated dll in the second project.
I am getting all the fields in the Second project just the **QUERY** variable is not visible in the second project.

Can anyone guide me on why this is happening?

Thanks!!

Comment: this sounds like a deployment issue, i.e. the second project has an older copy of the dll; how is the reference being added?

Comment: @MarcGravell I had added it under the reference section of the project.

Under reference> add refrence > browse the path of dll and added it

Comment: you're probably better off using a "project reference" or a "package reference" than a "dll reference" - it'll stay updated better

Comment: Is there a specific reason the two projects can't be part of the same solution?  I agree that this is very likely a problem with the reference and not with the code.  There's nothing in the code shown that would cause this behavior.